# How to add a request header in Nancyfx?

Tags: c#, web, nancy

I tried adding this in the bootstrapper in the ApplicationStartup override.

```
pipelines.AfterRequest.AddItemToStartOfPipeline(ctx =>
{
  ctx.Request.Headers["x-fcr-version"] = "1";
});
```

Its giving me errors.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Notice how you are trying to set the `Request` while trying to manipulate the `Response` ?

Try this..

```
protected override void RequestStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines, NancyContext context)
{
    base.RequestStartup(container, pipelines, context);

    pipelines.AfterRequest.AddItemToEndOfPipeline(c =>
    {
        c.Response.Headers["x-fcr-version"] = "1";
    });
}
```

This is what my `Response` looks like..

[image]

Or .. you can use [Connection Negotiation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Content-Negotiation) if you're going to set it at the module level...

```
Get["/"] = parameters => {
    return Negotiate
        .WithModel(new RatPack {FirstName = "Nancy "})
        .WithMediaRangeModel("text/html", new RatPack {FirstName = "Nancy fancy pants"})
        .WithView("negotiatedview")
        .WithHeader("X-Custom", "SomeValue");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is about adding headers to a nancy **request**, which I need to do as I need to add an origin header, and some others when making requests to my app api.

In order to get it to work, I did the following:

```
    //create headers dictionary
    var myHeaders = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>();
    myHeaders.Add("origin",new List<String>{"https://my.app.com"});
    //..... snip - adding other headers ....//  

    var uri = new Uri("https://my.api.com");
    var request = new Nancy.Request("OPTIONS", uri, null, myHeaders,"127.0.0.1", null);
```

I found reading the [nancy request source source](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/Request.cs) useful, as the null parameters, (*body* and *protocolVersion*) and  I passed through get initialized  if not set.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the answer with content negotiation is not working in my case but I found another way:

```
Get["result"] = x=>
{
    ...

    var response = Response.AsText(myModel, "application/json");
    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://example.com");
    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

    return response;
  };
```

Comment: Hello, what is myModel in this example? Is it a Nancy module?

Comment: Hi! No, it's not a Nancy module. It is a string which contains the response in plain text which will be sent to a browser.